# Jquery Datepicker-Tooltip to display a sql result

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, tooltip

First, I am a PHP guy, JS, Jquery I do not have a good knowledge on.  I have searched google the last 3 days for a solution to my problem, to no avail. 
What I am trying to do is in the Jquery Datepicker is when your mouse is laying on a date a tooltip would appear and show you the events/activities for that date.  I got an open source calendar called wdCalendar, and am trying to modify their code to achieve this.  I have found where their current tooltip is, and I can write text in the code, and have it displayed in the tooltip, but I do not know how to pull up a php file to run the query to db.  or is there a way for jquery to query the db.  I hope I am being specific enough.  Here is part of the code where the tooltip is.  The empty quotes after "'title='",.  Any suggestions, ideas or solutions I am truely grateful for.  I didn't want to paste in the whole code because its 500+ lines, but if you want to see that also, let me know.

```
bhm.push("<td class='", tdc.join(" "), "' title='", "" , "' xdate='", dateFormat.call(ndate, i18n.datepicker.dateformat.fulldayvalue), "'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><em><span>", ndate.getDate(), "</span></em></a></td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your query results into the tooltip, you'll want to look at POSTing the data via `.ajax()` [(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your PHP script (which queries the database) and returning it back via XML or JSON. From there, you can manipulate the titles of the HTML using jQuery.

I suggest trying this in a separate script to get familiar with the function and what it does before integrating it.  Once you've done that, you'll attach a `.hover()` event over the "appointments" (looks like they're called `.chip dl` in that particular calendar), which will fire the AJAX request, return the JSON/XML, which you can use to populate the tooltip.